# MongoDB Inserting audio

Tags: mongodb, audio

I have inserted one million documents containing text into mongodb database through javascript and php. I would like to know how to insert one million documents related to audio/image into the database.

The script I used for inserting text :

```
var minDate = new Date(2012, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
var maxDate = new Date(2013, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
var delta = maxDate.getTime() - minDate.getTime();

var job_id = arg2;

var documentNumber = arg1;
var batchNumber = 5 * 1000;

var job_name = 'Job#' + job_id
var start = new Date();

var batchDocuments = new Array();
var index = 0;

while(index < documentNumber) {
    var date = new Date(minDate.getTime() + Math.random() * delta);
    var value = Math.random();
    var document = {       
        created_on : date,
        value : value
    };
    batchDocuments[index % batchNumber] = document;
    if((index + 1) % batchNumber == 0) {
        db.randomData.insert(batchDocuments);
    }
    index++;
    if(index % 100000 == 0) {  
        print(job_name + ' inserted ' + index + ' documents.');
    }
}
print(job_name + ' inserted ' + documentNumber + ' in ' + (new Date() - start)/1000.0 + 's');
```

Can a similar script be used to insert Audio/Image as well?

Thanks.

Comment: First of all this is not the way to go when you need to insert many documents. Please read [Write Operations Overview](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/write-operations-introduction/#write-operations-overview). That being said, MongoDB provides an efficient way  for storing files and that is [GridFS](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/gridfs/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but you'll need a powerful interpreter to accomplish this. It is possible to insert binary data into MongoDB using BinData, which needs a base64 string and cat() doesn't convert binary to string besides it fails reading binary data.

A quick workaround could be get the base64 string, save to a file, then read with cat() in your script. Example in node.js:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var b64Str = fs.readFileSync('file.mp3','base64');
fs.writeFileSync('base64ContentFile',b64Str);
```

Do it for every file you want to put in the database, then run your script changing the following:

```
var document = {
    created_on : date,
    value : new BinData(0,cat('base64ContentFile'))
};
```

A better solution would be use another language, a mongodb driver and do everything there. Read one file, parse it to a base64 string then insert into db, loop.

https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/#binary

Comment: converting a binary blob to base64 for storage is likely to be a pretty inefficient use of space. It'll be 33% longer than the binary